# Axis2 Weblogic 10 jar conflict

Tags: java, weblogic, apache-axis, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to deploy a axis2 webservice client on Weblogic 10 server. However i get the below error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory    at
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:136)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppHelper$IOHelperImpl.parseXML(WebAppHelper.java:247)
>     at
>   weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorCache.parseXML(DescriptorCache.java:350)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppHelper.parseTagLibraries(WebAppHelper.java:142)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppHelper.(WebAppHelper.java:60)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.(WebAppServletContext.java:402)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.(WebAppServletContext.java:452)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:410)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:582)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:298)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:93)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:360)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:56)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:46)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:615)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:147)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:61)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:189)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:87)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:719)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1186)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:248)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:157)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:157)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:45)
>     at
>   weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:464)
>     at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
>     at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)cuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)

My weblogic-application.xml is as follows:

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
<wls:package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</wls:package-name>
<wls:package-name>javax.xml.*</wls:package-name>
<wls:package-name>org.apache.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>

</wls:weblogic-application>
```

All help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue:
The weblogic-application.xml should be:

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
<wls:package-name>org.apache.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>

</wls:weblogic-application>
```

So that it picks up the weblogic stax-api implementation jar. Also there is no direct way to get weblogic stax parser to work with Axis2 1.5.2. So you need to have woodstock parser in the class path.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is same with CXF. I tried all these approaches and ended up putting huge package list. Finally gave up as we decided to use Tomcat.

The above list given is only apache classes, you may have to add more packages for dependencies and beyond.

Refer: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-WebLogic

Comment: Yes Weblogic has huge jar conflict issues with third party xml libraries. So the best thing to do is use the Weblogic implementation of JAX-WS(Weblogic webservices) if we want to avoid jar conflicts.