# java axis2 web service show 500 internal error

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Today, my web service show below error. It comes from migration of my webServices (from JDK6 on weblogic 10.3.4 to JDK7 on weblogic 12.1.3) . It really scared me a lot. I am not sure whether it is the code program or Weblogic server problem?

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.util.WSDLDefinitionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.DefinitionImpl
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeWSDL(WSDLWriterImpl.java:87)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printDefinitionObject(AxisService.java:1031)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printUserWSDL(AxisService.java:1058)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1332)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:198)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:258)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Comment: I find the link and will try in this weekend. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067337/axis2-weblogic-10-jar-conflict

Comment: Tried but still failed with same message. I added <container-descriptor>
  <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
 </container-descriptor>                     to weblogic.xml

Comment: Please help. I am still get fall in this problem.

Comment: My colleagues give me the link. I will try later and will mention whether solved or not.  https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=xvqrfdt22_9&_afrLoop=442209457260629#SYMPTOM

Comment: It is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error, never understood why and never came across any proper solution.

Understood that javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar and javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.jar libraries were not added to my WEB-INF/lib folder by default, added the two libraries, and everything worked properly when I re-ran the web app.